# NSDate Main Bundle Crash

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

In NSDate+DateTools by Matthew York, there's a line that's crashing for me:

```
#ifndef DateToolsLocalizedStrings
#define DateToolsLocalizedStrings(key) \
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, @"DateTools", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DateTools.bundle"]], nil)
#endif
```

I moved files into this new XCode project from another Xcode project. So I think it's looking in the mainBundle for something that doesn't exist? I'm not really sure what's going on. Thanks....

Comment: 1. is this OSX or iOS? 2. Where is the full error message, add it to the question. 3.Don't use #define, notice how it is hard to debug. 4.This should be a multi statement method, probably a class method. 5. What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It seems to me the most likely scenario is that the DateTools.bundle is not in my App bundle. How would I check this?

Comment: If you did not put it there it isn't there.

Comment: Right, now is there a way to see this in xcode?

Comment: Okay, so how do I get that file/bundle?

Answer (score 0):

This is very unsafe coding. You need to check that each argument is actually returning something that is not nil. Even resourcePath has the possibility of returning nil, but in your case it is most likely that "DateTools.bundle" is either missing or is in the wrong place in the App bundle.

I really do not like concise code like this. It saves nothing useful, and makes debugging painful.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How do I access the App bundle and see if it's there?

Comment: Use "Archive" in Xcode, and then use finders Show PackageContents to move into your apps package

Comment: Okay, so how do I get that file/bundle if I don't have it?